# Sinatra can't see styles.css

Tags: sinatra

In my directory I have:

- shop.rb (App < Sinatra::Base)
- lib directory - Ruby models inside
- views directory - erb files inside
- Gemfile

Where should I place my style.css ? I tried every place possible, I created public folder and tried with also every possible place, but my styles doesn't work.
In layout I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"/>
```

I tried also with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the app is not configured to find the public directory/ First make sure the public directory exists relative to the main entry file of your application (assuming shop.rb) and use the following configuration:

```
class Shop < Sinatra::Base
   configure do
     set :public_folder, File.expand_path('../public', __FILE__)
     set :views        , File.expand_path('../views', __FILE__)
     set :root         , File.dirname(__FILE__)
   end

   get '/' do
     erb :index
   end
 end
```

Once set up, Sinatra should now know where to find your public directory and you can just include the asset file like this:

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"/>
```

Image:

```
<img src="/img/background.png" alt="Image" />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```